# In-app billing strange response codes

Tags: android

I have in-app billing purchases handled like this:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(
    activity, itemID, 12345, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "myrandomtoken"
);

// snip snip

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = 
new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        int purchaseResult = result.getResponse();
    }
}
```

Google lists server response codes on this page: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html but the problem is I'm getting some strange codes instead, like -1005 (user canceled) instead of 1, and the same response when the app is not correctly signed (deliberately) when I should be getting response 5. Google Play displays a little dialog with the error and then when the user exits that dialog Google Play returns response -1005.

So my question is how/where do I get the response codes that are listed at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Google's `IabHelper.java` (mistakenly or not) returns the response as canceled no matter which reason it gets from the server. In `IabHelper.java` I just replaced:

```
result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_USER_CANCELLED, "User canceled.");
```

with

```
result = new IabResult(responseCode, "Actual reason description.");
```

so now IabHelper returns the actual reason the purchase was not successful.